# Yii: how to format datetime in view and search by year

Tags: php, datetime, yii

I have this code:

```
array(
        'name'=>'create_time',
        'type'=>'datetime',
        'filter'=>Lookup::items('create_time'),
    ),
```

I want:

1. Date to be 01.03.2009 16:09:47, not 2009/01/03 04:09:47 AM (and full month name - with specific language)
2. Filters with only year

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more Yii orientated way would be:

```
'value'=>'Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("d.m.y h:i:s",strtotime($data->datetime))',
```

Comment: Ok, now i must have searching by only year. Now date doesn't displaying.
<pre>
'value'=>'Lookup::item("PostTime", Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", $data->create_time))',
   'filter'=>Lookup::items('PostTime'),</pre>

Comment: In what way doesn't it display? Do you need to use `strtotime()`

Comment: Using strtotime, doesn't work: Lookup::item("PostTime", Yii::app()->dateFormatter->format("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss", strtotime($data->create_time)))

Answer (score 1):

```
array(
    'name'=>'create_time',
    'value'=>'date("d.m.y h:i:s", $data->datetime)',
    'filter'=>Lookup::items('create_time'),
),
```

You can change the date function if you want to show date in other formats.. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php list of all supported formats..